# unable to click on button using codeceptjs with protractor

Tags: codeceptjs

I tried to debug with verbose command and here is the output
I see element "//span[contains(text(),'Save')]//ancestor::button"
    Emitted | step.passed (I see element "//span[contains(text(),'Save')]//ancestor::button")
    Emitted | step.finish (I see element "//span[contains(text(),'Save')]//ancestor::button")
    Emitted | step.start (I grab number of visible elements "//span[contains(text(),"Save")]//ancestor::button")
    I grab number of visible elements "//span[contains(text(),"Save")]//ancestor::button"
    Emitted | step.passed (I grab number of visible elements "//span[contains(text(),"Save")]//ancestor::button")
    Emitted | step.finish (I grab number of visible elements "//span[contains(text(),"Save")]//ancestor::button")
    Emitted | step.start (I click "//span[contains(text(),'Save')]//ancestor::button")
    I click "//span[contains(text(),'Save')]//ancestor::button"
    [1] Retrying... Attempt #2
    [1] Retrying... Attempt #3
    [1] Retrying... Attempt #4
    [1] Retrying... Attempt #5
    [1] Retrying... Attempt #6
    [1] Error | WebDriverError: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (808, 473). Other element would receive the click: 
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)
Even though it is able to locate the element, click is not working.
Any idea how to use executescript method in codeceptjs.

Comment: Please format your question. I don't see where is your text and where code/logs - I don't know what is it.

Comment: i am unable to click on a button using codeceptjs with protractor

Below is the Error message i got in codeceptjs
I click "//span[contains(text(),'Save')]//ancestor::button" [1] Retrying... Attempt #2 [1] Retrying... Attempt #3 [1] Retrying... Attempt #4 [1] Retrying... Attempt #5 [1] Retrying... Attempt #6 [1] Error | WebDriverError: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (808, 473). Other element would receive the click: (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)

Comment: I tried to provide CSS Selector as well. Below code works in chrome console.
('#.badged-button.mat-raised-button.mat-primary').click()

But, if i provide using I.executeScript method it is not working

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to resolve the issue at hand.

1. Remove number of elements found method and instead, use

```
I.seeElement(#id)
```

2. Add a pause method before the step which is having the issue and debug on the go.

```
I.pause();
```

3. Generally while writing test scripts ; before clicking any button always use

```
I.see(#id);
```

Lastly, don't complicate action as simple as a click by adding Executescript method
Let me know if you still face issue.

PS - Please format your question when you ask it here. For reference check other questions.